# Is it possible to change 'From: root@example.com (Cron Daemon)' to conform to RFC 5322 angle-addr or name-addr format?

Tags: 18.04, server, cron, email, postfix

When my server sends messages generated by cron jobs, the all have the following From: header:

```
From: root@relayclient.example.com (Cron Daemon)
```

Based on answers in [this Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1090902/is-the-postfix-from-address-rfc-compliant-for-cron-jobs) I am concluding this is a legacy format that SHOULD NOT be used based on this note in RFC 5322 [3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#section-3.4.1):

> Note: Some legacy implementations used the simple form where the
>       addr-spec appears without the angle brackets, but included the
>       name of the recipient in parentheses as a comment following the
>       addr-spec.  Since the meaning of the information in a comment is
>       unspecified, implementations SHOULD use the full name-addr form of
>       the mailbox, instead of the legacy form, to specify the display
>       name associated with a mailbox.  Also, because some legacy
>       implementations interpret the comment, comments generally SHOULD
>       NOT be used in address fields to avoid confusing such
>       implementations.

Here are the above referenced specifications:

```
name-addr       =   [display-name] angle-addr
angle-addr      =   [CFWS] "<" addr-spec ">" [CFWS] /
                    obs-angle-addr
addr-spec       =   local-part "@" domain
```

Since `postfix` uses From: headers generated by other system daemons that conform to addr-spec, I am assuming this is some sort of an issue related to `cron`, but I may be wrong on that, as I am not clear how these are configured, but it is for all messages generated by cron jobs.

Is it possible to change the From: header to conform to the referenced specifications for cron jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [not possible](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=898177) to change the From: address for cron jobs. This is hard-coded and it is specific to Debian cron.

A February 2021 [commit to salsa](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/cron/-/commit/1d904fb79cfc732cdda0c45800258580c727555b) includes a fix to optionally change the From: address.